# Load specific CSS files from JavaScript in Rails

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm working on taking a html5up template that I really like and put it in rails. I have it all working except for one thing. In the js they have this

```
skel.init({
        reset: 'full',
        breakpoints: {
            'global':   { range: '*', href: 'css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 40 }, viewport: { scalable: false } },
            'wide':     { range: '961-1880', href: 'css/style-wide.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
            'normal':   { range: '961-1620', href: 'css/style-normal.css', containers: 960, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
            'narrow':   { range: '961-1320', href: 'css/style-narrow.css', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 20 } },
            'narrower': { range: '-960', href: 'css/style-narrower.css', containers: '100%', grid: { gutters: 15 } },
            'mobile':   { range: '-736', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', grid: { collapse: true } }
        },
```

Which loads a certain css file depending on what size screen you have. This works fine when its just being loaded using apache but in rails all css gets throw together into an application.css when its in assets/stylesheets which means i wont be able to do anything like this. Is there any way to keep these css files separate and load them dynamically from js like it is here?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. i just put in into public and then just referenced it from ../stylesheets/mycss.css